# Extending native HTML elements and Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element, polymer-2.x

Is there a way to extend native elements (eg. `HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLTableElement` etc) instead of `Polymer.Element` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your question is **not as of now**. The reason behind the same is that all the browsers have not agreed to implement this that's why [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#extending-other-elements) has not implemented it yet.

> Polymer does not currently support extending built-in elements. The custom elements spec provides a mechanism for extending built-in elements, such as  and . The spec calls these elements customized built-in elements. Customized built-in elements provide many advantages (for example, being able to take advantage of built-in accessibility features of UI elements like  and ). However, not all browser makers have agreed to support customized built-in elements, so Polymer does not support them at this time.